# How to upload multiple FilePicker files in Flutter web app?

Tags: flutter

How to upload multiple FilePicker files in Flutter web app?  I have a list of File Picker Result and would like to upload to our server.  My colleagues has completed an api for me to upload files and is proved working in PostMan:

[image]

I make use of FilePicker class to allow the user to select multiple files to upload

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Testing"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async{
                FileList = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);
                if (FileList != null) {
                  for(var i = 0; i < FileList!.count; i++) {
                    print(FileList!.files[i].name);
                  }
                } else {
                  // User canceled the picker
                }
              },
              child: Text('select files'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async{

                // what to do here?

              },
              child: Text('upload'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the files to the `MutliPartFile` list as you have to send the images in `FormData` format.

```
void pickFiles() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      allowMultiple: true,
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'pdf', 'doc'],
    );
  if (result != null) {
  List<MultipartFile> files = result.files
      .map((file) => MultipartFile.fromBytes(
            file.bytes as List<int>,
            filename: file.name,
          ))
      .toList();

  var formData = FormData.fromMap({
    'id': '',
    'type': '',
    'docType': '',
    'files': files,
  });
  for (var element in formData.files) {
    print(element.value.filename);
  }
}
```

Pass the `formData` to the API calls in the body.

Comment: It has quite a lot of compile errors including:

lib/main.dart:47:13: Error: A prefix can't be used as an expression.
            path,
            ^^^^
lib/main.dart:48:37: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
            filename: path.basename(imgPath),

Comment: i have not tried the code myself so there may be some of those errors. but you get the idea, right?

Comment: because this is the first time I try to upload files in web app ......, so would you mind ?

Comment: Seems like `MultipartFile.fromFileSync` is not supported in web, you have to use `MultipartFile.fromBytes`. I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks Sujan, it works! and is able to work with our api by adding:

var dio = Dio();
      try {
        var response = await dio.post(url, data: formData);
        print(response.statusCode);
        return response.data;
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }